# NVIDIA eGPU - Crashes after some time

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, laptop, external-monitor, thunderbolt

We're experiencing the following error, after some time working on a laptop:

```
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria kernel: [  110.645559] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.2: remove, state 1
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria kernel: [  110.645565] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria kernel: [  110.645914] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.2: Host halt failed, -19
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria kernel: [  110.645919] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.2: Host not accessible, reset failed.
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria kernel: [  110.646050] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.2: USB bus 3 deregistered
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria upowerd[6486]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:01.0/0000:0b:00.2/usb4/4-0:1$
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria upowerd[6486]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:01.0/0000:0b:00.2/usb3/3-0:1$
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria upowerd[6486]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:01.0/0000:0b:00.2/usb3
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria upowerd[6486]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:01.0/0000:0b:00.2/usb4
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 25
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria snapd[3208]: udevmon.go:147: udev event error: Unable to parse uevent, err: cannot parse libudev event: invalid env data
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 24
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria snapd[3208]: udevmon.go:147: udev event error: Unable to parse uevent, err: cannot parse libudev event: invalid env data
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria snapd[3208]: udevmon.go:147: udev event error: Unable to parse uevent, err: cannot parse libudev event: invalid env data
Mar 29 14:09:13 lBoria snapd[3208]: udevmon.go:147: udev event error: Unable to parse uevent, err: cannot parse libudev event: invalid env data
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8293]: [9297:9297:0329/140914.320368:ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(1110)] RasterDecoder context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status $
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.171486] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.171771] pci_bus 0000:0b: busn_res: [bus 0b] is released
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.171861] pci_bus 0000:0a: busn_res: [bus 0a-3d] is released
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.172114] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8293]: [9297:9297:0329/140914.320424:ERROR:raster_decoder.cc(868)]   RasterDecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria org.gnome.Shell.desktop[8293]: [9297:9297:0329/140914.324340:ERROR:gpu_service_impl.cc(949)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers can't recover from err$
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.217335] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Failed to query display engine channel state: 0x0000c57e:0:0:0x00000023
Mar 29 14:09:14 lBoria kernel: [  111.217343] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Failed to query display engine channel state: 0x0000c57e:2:0:0x00000023
```

OS: **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**

External eGPU (Thunderbolt 3):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f06 (rev a1)
```

$ glxinfo -B

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 8192 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7207 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Laptop:
Lenovo Yoga 720

Using the following script for eGPU switching:
https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher